# Using cython when arguments and returns are matrices, not scalars

Tags: python, pandas, cython

I am new to cython and I would like to make calculations on pandas DataFrames faster. Here is a typical, simplified example of such calculations. In this example, the arguments are vectors and the return is a scalar but in other cases both arguments and returns can be DataFrame/arrays. I have many of these functions, and they are sometimes nested.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def f(x,y,z):
  return np.dot(x,np.exp(x*y/(1-np.power(z,3))))

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(1000), 'b': 
np.random.randn(1000),'c': np.random.randint(100, 1000, (1000))})

print(f(df.a,df.b,df.c))
```

In the tutorials and documentation that I have seen, cython is used to optimize computations on scalars, not matrices/arrays (for example http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html). So the process typically involves adding types to scalars (int, float, double, etc.). What is the right process to make use of cython where your functions use DataFrames or arrays as arguments and returns, not scalars?

I have tried the following, but failed to see any noticeable improvement (although no errors were thrown):

```
@cython.locals(x=cython.float,y=cython.float,z=cython.float)   
@cython.returns(cython.float)  
def f(x,y,z):
  return np.dot(x,np.exp(x*y/(1-np.power(z,3))))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fact you don't see errors probably tells you that you aren't actually compiling it with Cython (you're passing it arrays, but you've told Cython you're passing it scalars). You do need to run the `cython` command on your file, then build it with C - it isn't enough just to add decorators.

Comment: That said I agree with Cristián Antuña's answer - this isn't code which will see much improvement with Cython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look inside your function: you are only calling numpy functions, that is, you leave a small (if any) margin for Cython to translate to C code.

You **may** gain speed if you type your variables as, say, double[:] for arrays (honestly, I don't see where, but compiler's optimizations are typically smarter than oneself). But still your function is mainly a wrapper for numpy ones: Cython won't improve their internal working.

You could try to implement your own external product function, though, and gain some speed there (I don't know how efficient is numpy's one, but you can probably beat it for a little margin). Plus, using C's `exp` and `pow` from `math.h` might improve a bit further.

Cython is nos just 'type-definign' variables but you have to make sure that, when calling cython's compiler, it will be able to translate as much of your code to C as possible. (By the way, you are compiling your code, right? The speed boost will be only seen if you compile your source and import the resulting module; running it in pure-python mode is just Python).

Comment: Thanks, clear. I do compile my code, yes. And as you say, I see no improvement. I will try with 'double' and let you know what I have.